# Is there a reason for not using JavaScript for direct database connections on a web site?

Tags: javascript, database

I am thinking about using JavaScript for direct connection to our database server. I think I have solutions to all the possible problems about it.

- Security: Modern database management systems support SSL connections (e.g.
  PostgreSQL). We can securely connect to a DBMS. There is no
  difference between securely connecting to a database and securely
  connecting to an application server.
- Authorization: We can define [stored procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) in modern database
  management systems. We can define the functional interface of users
  by using stored procedures and functions. We can authorize users to
  use only selected ones of those procedures. We can restrict them from
  using any of create, drop, select, insert, etc. statements.
- Efficient bandwidth usage: Modern database management systems support data
  compression. We can get much more compressed raw data from a database server
  for unit bandwidth and decompress and "HTMLize" that raw data on the client by using the client's computing resources (distributed computing is a plus).
- We can use an HTTP server to serve static HTML+JavaScript pages.
  Because the pages will be all static, the HTTP server will cache web
  pages much more efficiently and this will increase performance.

So I think there is nothing wrong with using a two-tier system on current DBMS and browser technologies. Any objections?